# Hibernate Filter Programmatically

Tags: hibernate, filter, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

How to programmatically achieve the same result (as the following annotation would achieve)?  Or injecting the value 'SMITH' in a spring configuration file?

```
@Filter(name="smithFilter", condition="LAST_NAME = 'SMITH'")
public String getLastName()
{
    return this.lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define a FilterDef with the parameters the filter condition will receive:

```
@FilterDef(name = "smithFilter", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "lastName", type = "string")})
@Filter(name="smithFilter", condition="LAST_NAME = :lastName")
```

As you also used the word "programmatically", you may also want to know that you can set the parameter based on other inputs, like this:

```
session.enableFilter("smithFilter").setParameter("lastName", "SMITH");
```

More details in Hibernate documentation:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters